# Error while installing termkit

Tags: software-installation

Here is an error I'm receiving while installing termkit:

```
npm ERR! Error: Not found: connect@'>=1.2.0- <1.3.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["latest","0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6","0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.5.3","0.5.4","0.5.5","0.5.6","0.5.7","0.5.8","0.5.9","0.5.10","1.0.0","1.0.1"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:313:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:306:17
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:134:7)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:31:9)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.39-02063901-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.3-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.22
npm ERR!
n    pm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm not ok
```

Any ideas?

Comment: dependencies seem to be missing: `Error: Not found: connect@'>=1.2.0- <1.3.0-'`  Do you ahve this installed?

Comment: I can't seem to find connect in repo or anywhere for that matter

Comment: I tried installing connect-proxy which was in repo but that didn't help, even I thought its dependency. I think it depends on socket.io which was a part of termkit but not anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I've been buggin Floby (Termkit developer) about the issue.
And looks like node v0.5.3-pre is not stable yet

So I went back to node v0.4.10 and it worked just fine.
If anyone wanna try

use:

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git reset --hard 1b8dd65d6e3b82b6863e
```

Continue with http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/termkit-is-terminal-reimagined-install.html these instructions that worked for me :)